# Matlab to python - different results, cannot solve

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matplotlib

I have been trying to convert the following matlab code into python and I am having difficulties with construction of the matrix algebra.

The product of the python code is vastly different from matlab and I can't figure out the problem (I assume its in the matrix multiplication).

Just for some background info: Using the data set, I was attempting to create a forecast with one dummy varialbe 'D1'

Here is the matlab code:

```
load 'AUSRetail.csv'

y = AUSRetail(:,1); Q = AUSRetail(:,2);
T = length(y); t = (1:T)';
D4 = (Q == 4);
T0 = 15;
h = 1; % h−step−ahead forecast
syhat = zeros(T-h-T0+1,1);
ytph = y(T0+h:end); % observed y {t+h}
for t = T0:T-h
    yt = y(1:t);
    D4t = D4(1:t);
    Xt = [ones(t,1) (1:t)' D4t];
    beta2 = (Xt'*Xt)\(Xt'*yt);
    yhat2 = [1 t+h D4(t+h)]*beta2;
    syhat(t-T0+1) = yhat2;
end
MSFE2 = mean((ytph-syhat).^2);

plot([1:T], y)
hold on 
plot([T0 + h:T], syhat)
```

and here is my python code attempt:

```
data = pd.read_csv("dataretail.csv").dropna()

D4 = np.asarray(data["Dummy4"])
dataValues = np.asarray(data["Value"])
T = len(D4)
T0 = 15
h = 1

syhat = []
ytph = np.asarray(dataValues) # Real values to test against
for t in range(T0,T-1):
    yt = dataValues[:t].reshape(t,1)

    D4t = D4[:t]

    #Construction of Xt
    xt1 = np.ones((t,1))
    xt2 = np.arange(1,t+1).reshape(t,1)
    xt3 = D4t.reshape(t,1)
    Xt = np.column_stack((xt1,xt2,xt3))
    Xt2 = np.transpose(Xt)

    A = Xt2 @ Xt
    b = Xt2 @ yt
    beta2 = np.transpose(A) @ b
    yhat2 = np.array([1, t+h, D4[t+h]]) @ beta2
    syhat.append(int(yhat2))


fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 1])
axes.set_xlabel("T (time)")
axes.set_ylabel("Yhat2")
axes.plot(range(25), abc)
axes.set_title("Model")
```

Comment: Try plotting the values before the loop starts, also, try plotting them after only 1 iteration of the loop. See if they is a difference between the plots in Matlab and Python.

Comment: The reason I'm suggesting checking before the loop, is that your Matlab code has 1 more iteration than your Python code. In Matlab, you have `for t = T0:T-1` while in Python, you have `for t in range(T0,T-1)` (the function `range` does not include the last value, so the last iteration is when `t=T-2`). This could be the source of the inconsistency.

Comment: @Aziz Was a good idea. I plotted the data beforehand and they are the same (its basically a linear line with spikes every 4 periods (seasonal data). When I plot 'syhat' at the end, im expecting a similar thing, however, the graph is just an exponential curve (the seasonal data seems to be omitted entirely)

Comment: Following up on what Aziz said, your line "for t in range(T0,T-1):" also fails to take note of indices in Python starting from 0 whereas in Matlab they start at 1. Hence, T0 should be 14 in Python for the same effect.

Comment: First, you don't seem to be loading the same files. Matlab loads `AUSRetail.csv` whereas python loads `dataretail.csv`. Secondly, you `dropna()` in python which doesn't seem to be the case for Matlab. I think it is best to debug step by step. Then you can easily find where they differ.

Comment: I ran through everything and the data is the same, the for loop has been adjusted, however I am still receiving vastly different graphs. This is what it was supposed to look like: https://i.imgur.com/iIWj9Y4.png and this is what I received: https://i.imgur.com/5KcTuas.png